# UN Comtrade Database- what is the difference between a partnercode and reportercode

Tags: trade

I am working with the UN Comtrade database. Each observation is 2-dimensional and contains a partnercode and reportercode. What do these terms mean? I have tried to search the website for it, but to no avail.